# How to add new item to the data have ArrayList is property?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room

I have a model like below, I want to add a new item to friends data, but it's creating an infinite loop. So what should I do?

```
@Entity(tableName = "user_table")
class UserModel
    : Serializable {
    @PrimaryKey
    @NonNull
    var _id: String = ""

    var userName: String? = null

    var userAvatar: String? = null
    
    @TypeConverters(ConvertersDAO::class)
    var friends : ArrayList<String> = ArrayList()
}
```

My DAO interface

```
 @Update
    suspend fun updateUserDAO(userModel : UserModel)

    @Query("select * from user_table where _id =:id")
    fun readUserById(id : String) : LiveData<UserModel>
```

My converters

```
class ConvertersDAO {
    @TypeConverter
    fun fromString(value: String?): ArrayList<String?>? {
        val listType: Type = object : TypeToken<ArrayList<String?>?>() {}.type
        return Gson().fromJson(value, listType)
    }

    @TypeConverter
    fun fromArrayList(list: ArrayList<String?>?): String? {
        val gson = Gson()
        return gson.toJson(list)
    }
}
```

and What I have tried so far(but it works so bad)

```
private fun updateFriend() {
        val friendId = "foo"
        viewModel.readUserByIdDAO(userId).observe(this,{

            val listTemp = it.friends
            listTemp.add(friendId)
            it.friends = listTemp

            viewModel.updateUserDAO(it)
        })
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in the way that you are getting the `UserModel`. You're observing it as `LiveData`, and updating it in the same block and so each time you update the user this triggers the observable code block to be updated again and leads to this infinite loop.

A simple fix is to introduce a non `LiveData` way of getting the user from the database

```
@Query("select * from user_table where _id =:id")
suspend fun readUserByIdSync(id : String) : UserModel
```

Comment: oh i understood. thanks so much, have a nice day!